# How to store the time when button pressed and read it in another VC?

Tags: swift

I am making a calculation in Main VC and I want to store and read it with time in another VC as list (tableView). I don't have problem storing calculation result but I can't store the time. My main problem is time overriding and I couldn't find a way to fix it.

[Time overriding should have been 18:20, 18:21, 18:22, 18.24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEWOW.png)

```
     let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    let str = df.string(from: Date())
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(str, forKey: "key")

    if let strOut = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "key") {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = strOut
    }
```

Comment: 1. Why are you storing a string representation of the date instead of the actual `Date` instance? 2. What is your actual issue? Please [edit] your question and clearly explain what your problem is. Show expected and actual results in your question. 3. Do not use `setValue(_:forKey:)`, use `set(_:forKey:)`. Only use `setValue(_:forKey:)` and `value(forKey:)` if you have a clearly understood need for key-value coding.

Comment: You need a variable outside your view controllers...

Answer (score 0):

As rmaddy pointed out, `UserDefaults` supports storage of `Date`.

```swift
let date = Date()
UserDefaults.standard.set(date, forKey: "key")
```

You would then pull it at a later point via:

```swift
guard let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "key") as? Date else { return }
```